# jquery case statement not working

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, conditional-statements, case

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img-1").click(function () {

        switch (true) {
            case $("#div2").load("borrower-information.html"):
                alert(hello);

                break;
            case ($("#div3").load("demo_test.html #p3")):
                break;

            case ($("#div4").load("demo_test.html #p4")):
                alert('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

guys i have make 3 div and there was one button with the id name is id=img-1 after clicking the page load from other source its ok but my query is that alert is not working why?

Comment: What is it you are expecting this switch to do? `switch(true)` sounds a bit odd.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `case` statement. *JavaScript* does, though.

Comment: `switch(true)` is always `true/1`.

Comment: You need to learn about the `switch` statement, what you've written makes no sense

Comment: load is async and return a promise interface, so this couldn't work anyway

Comment: @SheikhHeera: Yes, but that doesn't mean any cases match it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I didn't say that, did I ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera: You said "`switch (true)` is always `true/1`" which doesn't actually mean anything, because `switch` statements have no value. The relevant thing here is that none of the `case`s matches the value being tested.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes, that's what I said and it matches nothing and there is one case always, I just tried to make the `OP` clear but I didn't explain more.

Comment: case $("#div2").load("borrower-information.html"): this line tell that there is a div with id div2 in which we can load some data from other page i.e borrower-information.html for that i am using load method that's running properly but the query is that when my page "borrower-information.html" in my specified div it show me the alert msg but its not working these thing will be go on all the other cases.

Answer (score 3):

`switch (true)` means "choose the first `case` that evaluates to `true` using strict equality (`===`)". None of your cases evaluates to `true` using strict equality. They all result in `jqXHR` objects, which while truthy, are not `=== true`. So none of them matches.

This works, for instance:

```
var a = 42;
switch (true) {
    case a == 67:
        console.log("a == 67 is true");
        break;
    case a == 42:
        console.log("a == 42 is true");
        break;
}
```

...in that it makes `a == 42 is true` appear in the console, because the expression `a == 42` is `true` and thus it matches `switch (true)`. But it's a very, very unusual use of `switch`. There's probably a better way to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: can you please tell me in my coding where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, the event bindings are okay...